# Update value on the fields which have the same primary key

Tags: sql

I'm stuck at a problem which I need help with:

I have simple table like below,

[image: table]

I want the `SKU A`'s INV field value to remain and update other `SKU`s with %20 of `SKU A`'s `INV` value where `XREF` field equals to `SKU A`'s `XREF`.

Can somebody assist on how to write a SQL query for this logic?

Comment: If A, B, and C all have the same XREF value, how do you know that A is the "master" record?

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? I'm having a hard time figuring out what you want. And is `QTY` supposed to be a column name? In your sample data you have `INV`.

Comment: Please try to explain this question again.  I can't follow it either.

Comment: @AlexHowansky that's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: @mypetlion edited.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a wild guess.

I think that your sample data is not relevant. I understand that you want an update query to :

- leave intact all records having `SKU = 'A'`
- in all other records, update `INV` with 20% of the value of `INV` in the record where `SKU = 'A'` and `XREF` is the same as in the current record

Here is a query for that :

```
UPDATE 
    mytable t1
    INNER JOIN mytable t2 ON t2.sku = 'A' AND t2.xref = t1.xref
SET t1.inv = t2.inv * 0.2
WHERE t1.sku != 'A'
```

Please note that with this technique, records that can not be joined will not be updated (ie, if `XREF` is null or does not relate to a row where `SKU = 'A'`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, SKUA shouldn't only be the condition. Sorry that I didn't describe the issue clearly. But I have a bunch of SKU's which has the same case like SKUA with different Xref's. As @simonare said that will be a whole different scenario?

Comment: @YavuzB. : I guess that you would need to adapt and run this query for each use case.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below query.

the update statement has where constraint which only selects rows to be updated. The inner query on the other hand gets `t2.INV` with `SKU = 'A'`

```
update tbl t1
set INV = (select t2.INV * 0.2 from tbl t2 where t2.sku = 'A')
where XREF != null and SKU != 'A'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I apply this in Multiple SKU case?

Comment: you need to rephrase your question. that would be totally different context. It might need more complicated scenario. I cannot say more without without seeing the whole picture

Comment: Rephrased. Hoping that this would clarify my needs. Thanks

Comment: @YavuzBayhan apparently you dont know how to use StackOverflow. Your edited question is another question now and our answers are out of scope right now. This is a public community and right now community cannot benefit from our answers.  I advice you to open new question and rollback your last edit. (I did that for you)

Comment: For this question, please check our answers and if you believe that our answers are usefull and gives correct answer for your first question, please mark it as answer so that community can benefit from it.

Comment: Yes, as you can see from my profile, I was new to the community. However, you told me to rephrase the question, not to open a new one. I should have clarified more in detailed but this answer doesn't cover all my needs. Thank you anyways.